# ASP.NET 5 Web API Help Page?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

In ASP.NET MVC 4.5 or Web API 2.x, the help page could be easily generated. And doc comments of the API functions will go to the help page generated. In ASP.NET 5 RC1 as of today, I found this feature has gone apparently.

Is in the road map that the help page function could come back in ASP.NET 5 vNext official release Q1 2016? or in 5.1?

Comment: Take a look at Swashbuckler / Swagger: https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle

Comment: The feature is available as option via `NuGet`: https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.HelpPage/

Comment: The overhead of Swashbuckler is too much. I would expect something inheriting the good of Help Page of ASP.NET 4.5.

Comment: @tenbits, I am asking for ASP.NET 5, not MVC 5 of ASP.NET 4.5.

Answer (score 0):

Try to take a look at `AspNetX`: https://github.com/qqbuby/AspNetX